# Variable in path to directory

Tags: variables, vbscript, path

I'd like to use create a directory function with a timestamp in the name, and copy a file to it. I can't for the life of me figure out how I can use a variable in a path...

My code so far:

```
Function LPad(n) : LPad = Right("00" & n, 2) : End Function

timestamp = Year(Now) & LPad(Month(Now)) & LPad(Day(Now)) & LPad(Hour(Now)) & _
            LPad(Minute(Now)) & LPad(Second(Now))

Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folder2"


newdir = "NewDirectory" & timestamp

Dim oFSO

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


' Create a new folder

oFSO.CreateFolder(newdir)


' Copy a file into the new folder

oFSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folder1\Document1.doc", "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folder2\newdir"

'messagebox when complete

x=x=msgbox("Folder "& newdir & " Created Successfully" ,0, "Done")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [Concatenation Operator (&)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). 
You have to expand your variable (`newdir`) like this :

```
oFSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folder1\Document1.doc", "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folder2\" & newdir
```

Comment: Whelp, that was simple. Thanks for helping out a noob!